# Twisted transport.write in separate thread

Tags: python, multithreading, twisted

I want to receive the message from clients and send message to them through a separate independent process. The code I tried with uses the twisted method of threading. I tried to run the method sendMessage on a different thread to keep on receiving the message from client but it waits for the user to type the text. How is it possible to run sendMessage method in different thread so that program keeps on receiving the client's data even though message is not supplied from server side?
My Code:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory
from twisted.internet import reactor
import time

class MultiEcho(Protocol):
    def __init__(self, factory):
        self.factory = factory

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory.echoers.append(self)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print 'Client Said: ' + data
        reactor.callFromThread(self.sendMessage)

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.factory.echoers.remove(self)

    def sendMessage(self):
        app = raw_input('Send Message to client :')
        for echoer in self.factory.echoers:
            echoer.transport.write(app)




class MultiEchoFactory(Factory):
    def __init__(self):
        self.echoers = []

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return MultiEcho(self)


reactor.listenTCP(8000, MultiEchoFactory())
reactor.run()
```

Comment: You have the Queue class in Python, that you can use to pass messages between processes and threads, it is Thread and process safe, you also have deferToThread in Twisted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `raw_input` within Twisted. It blocks the main thread.  You can't call `transport.write` from a different thread, because all methods that use Twisted to do I/O must be called from the Twisted thread.

It looks like what you're trying to do here is to write a command-line program which takes standard-input (with line editing) and blasts that out to all currently-connected clients, and takes all input from those clients and sends it to the console.  Hopefully the following example shows how to accomplish something like that using Twisted's own APIs.

```
from twisted.python.failure import Failure

from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory

from twisted.conch.recvline import HistoricRecvLine
from twisted.conch.stdio import runWithProtocol

class ConsolePrompter(HistoricRecvLine, object):
    ps = ["Message: "]

    def __init__(self, multiEcho):
        self.multiEcho = multiEcho

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        try:
            if not line:
                reactor.stop()
            self.drawInputLine()
            self.multiEcho.tellAllClients(line)
        except:
            f = Failure()
            data = f.getTraceback()
            self.terminal.write(data)

    def clientSaid(self, data):
        self.terminal.write("\r")
        self.terminal.eraseLine()
        self.terminal.write("Client Said:" + repr(data))
        self.terminal.write("\n")
        self.drawInputLine()

class MultiEcho(Protocol):
    def __init__(self, factory):
        self.factory = factory

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory.echoers.append(self)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.factory.prompter.clientSaid(data)

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.factory.echoers.remove(self)

class MultiEchoFactory(Factory):
    def __init__(self):
        self.echoers = []
        self.prompter = ConsolePrompter(self)

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return MultiEcho(self)

    def tellAllClients(self, message):
        for echoer in self.echoers:
            echoer.transport.write(message + "\r\n")

mef = MultiEchoFactory()

reactor.listenTCP(8000, mef)

runWithProtocol(lambda: mef.prompter)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. When I tried to run this code, interpreter gave me strange error:
`<module>
    from twisted.conch.stdio import runWithProtocol
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\conch\stdio.py", line 11, in <module>
    import os, tty, sys, termios
  File "C:\Python27\lib\tty.py", line 5, in <module>
    from termios import *
ImportError: No module named termios`
What can be done in this scenario?

Comment: Aah... it was not clear from your example that you were on Windows :-\.  Console I/O on Windows is totally different, and a bit trickier.  This answer would be right for Linux or a Mac; hopefully someone else can answer for what the equivalent on Windows is.